# Access the queue from inside the Operation

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, nsoperationqueue, nsoperation

I'm using `Operation`s and `OperationQueue`s to download a series of videos. Here is my download `Operation`.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class VideoDownloader: Operation {
    let videoRecord: VideoRecord

    init(videoRecord: VideoRecord) {
        self.videoRecord = videoRecord
    }

    override func main() {
        if isCancelled {
            return
        }

        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: videoRecord.url)
        asset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)

        let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
        let filename = "\(videoRecord.id).mp4"

        let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask).last!
        let outputURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(filename)

        exporter?.outputURL = outputURL
        exporter?.outputFileType = .mp4

        exporter?.exportAsynchronously {
            if let error = exporter?.error {
                print(error)
            } else {
                print(outputURL)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension VideoDownloader: AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate {

}
```

This works fine. But I have a concern about the below line.

```
asset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
```

Currently I'm setting the delegate on the main thread. Which I don't think is correct because this runs in a background thread. I'm not sure so please correct me if I'm wrong here.

I thought it'd be best if I could set it's queue to the queue that operation is currently running on. But how can I access the queue from the operation class?

Comment: Are you using this to download video files from remote URLs ?

Comment: @SeanLintern88 Yes, that's right.

Comment: TBH, I have never seen an approach like this, usually you would download videos using UrlSessionDataTask, i know AVAssetExportSession does not work in the background so would fail if someone backgrounds the app

Answer (score 0):

Inside your main() you are using asynchronous APIs, like AVAssetExportSession and AVResourceLoaderDelegate, you should implement an asynchronous operation (Apple has documentations about this). You will have to change the state of some internal properties and call willChangeValueForKey and didChangeValueForKey so the OperationQueue gets notified when your asynchronous operation completes. If you don’t do this the OperationQueue will believe your operation will be completed as soon as the main() method returns. The OperationQueue will remove the operation from the queue and the maxConcurrentOperations will not be respected, because in reality your operation will still be running under the hood.

Because you are using asynchronous APIs that aren’t blocking and may run in various threads, I’d suggest just creating your own background queue or use an existing global queue for your AVResourceLoaderDelegate. Just keep the OperationQueue’s internal queue alone, it will act as a simple synchronization layer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I looked into asynchronous operations and came across [this article](http://swiftgazelle.com/2016/03/asynchronous-nsoperation-why-and-how/#comment-6472). So I modified my class accordingly. Here's the updated [version](https://pastebin.com/BThygXwL). Do you mean something like that?